# Java OpenGL, lights setup

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I am modeling a 3D maze in Java OpenGL (JOGL) and I am facing an issue about lights. No matter how hard I try lights don't act the way I want to.

This is setup in init method (which is called when the window is created):

```
    // nastaveni materialu - difusni slozka
    float[] mat_dif = new float[] { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f };
    // nastaveni materialu - zrcadlova slozka
    float[] mat_spec = new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    // nastaveni materialu - ambientni slozka
    float[] mat_amb = new float[] { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f };

    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, mat_amb, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, mat_dif, 0);
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, mat_spec, 0);


//nastaveni bileho svetla
float[] lightWhite = new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, lightWhite, 0);
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, lightWhite, 0);

//nastaveni cerveneho
float[] lightRed = new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, lightRed, 0);
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, lightRed, 0);

//nastaveni modreho
float[] lightBlue = new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT2, GL2.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, lightBlue, 0);
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT2, GL2.GL_SPECULAR, lightBlue, 0);
```

and code in display method (called when each frame is rendered)

```
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    light_position = new float[] {6.0f, 2.0f, -6.0f, 1.0f};// bod v prostoru
    light_direction = new float[] {0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f, 0.0f};

    light_position2 = new float[] {8.0f, 2.0f, -7.0f, 1.0f};// bod v prostoru
    light_direction2 = new float[] {15.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f, 0.0f};

    light_position3 = new float[] {8.0f, 2.0f, -4.0f, 1.0f};// bod v prostoru
    light_direction3 = new float[] {8.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_POSITION, light_position, 0);
    gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT0,GL2.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,60.0f);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, light_direction, 0);
    gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT0,GL2.GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,10.0f);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_POSITION, light_position2, 0);
    gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT1,GL2.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,60.0f);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, light_direction2, 0);
    gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT1,GL2.GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,10.0f);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT2, GL2.GL_POSITION, light_position3, 0);
    gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT2,GL2.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,35.0f);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT2, GL2.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, light_direction3, 0);
    gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT2,GL2.GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,10.0f);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glColorMaterial (GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, 
    GL2.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE ) ;
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT2);

    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
```

for better understending, there is a picture

[image]

after this code everything is dark and there is no light.
thank you so much for your time. :)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I added setting in edit.. so I can see some light (on 6x10) but it's just very little... in my opinion, the mistake is in setting direction or somethnig, what do you think? Is the setting ok due to my plan in photo?

Comment: @Rabbid76 so you are saying that I should insert pop and push between each command